# How can I put a bitmap image on a browse button in NSIS?

Tags: button, bitmap, nsis

I am working on an NSIS script. This script mainly contains customized pages.
I added a directory page using the following command:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
```

How can I add a bitmap image to an already existing "Browse..." button that will override the default text?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to use a "open folder icon" you can get it from the system:

```
!include WinMessages.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!include MUI2.nsh

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW CustDirShow
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

!define HIDEBROWSETEXT ; Remove "Browse..." text?

!ifdef HIDEBROWSETEXT
DirText "" "" " "
!endif
!define /ifndef FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY 0x10
!define /ifndef SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES 0x0010
!define /ifndef SHGFI_ICON              0x0100
!define /ifndef SHGFI_OPENICON          0x0002
!define /ifndef SHGFI_SMALLICON         0x0001
!define /ifndef SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX      0x4000

Var BrowseIcon
Function CustDirShow
${If} $BrowseIcon P= 0 ; Only load the icon once
    System::Call '*(p,i,i,&t260,&t80,&l.r1)p.r0'
    System::Call 'SHELL32::SHGetFileInfo(t "c:\x", i ${FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY}, pr0, ir1, i ${SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES}|${SHGFI_ICON}|${SHGFI_SMALLICON}|${SHGFI_OPENICON}|${SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX})'
    System::Call '*$0(p.s)'
    System::Free $0
    Pop $BrowseIcon ; This could also be a HICON from LoadImage etc
${EndIf}
!ifdef HIDEBROWSETEXT
${NSD_AddStyle} $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton ${BS_ICON}
!endif
SendMessage $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton ${BM_SETIMAGE} ${IMAGE_ICON} $BrowseIcon
FunctionEnd

Function .onGUIEnd
System::Call 'USER32::DestroyIcon(p $BrowseIcon)'
FunctionEnd
```

You can comment out `HIDEBROWSETEXT` to display the text as well but that only works on Vista and later, older versions of Windows do not support image+text on a normal button.

Loading a custom .bmp bitmap can be done like this:

```
...

Var BrowseIcon
Function CustDirShow
${If} $BrowseIcon P= 0 ; Only load the icon once
    InitPluginsDir
    File "/oname=$PluginsDir\broimg.bmp" "${NSISDIR}\Contrib\Graphics\Header\nsis.bmp"
    System::Call 'USER32::LoadImage(p0, t "$PluginsDir\broimg.bmp", i ${IMAGE_BITMAP}, i 16, i 16, i ${LR_LOADFROMFILE}|${LR_CREATEDIBSECTION})p.s'
    Pop $BrowseIcon
${EndIf}
!ifdef HIDEBROWSETEXT
${NSD_AddStyle} $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton ${BS_BITMAP}
!endif
SendMessage $mui.DirectoryPage.BrowseButton ${BM_SETIMAGE} ${IMAGE_BITMAP} $BrowseIcon
FunctionEnd

Function .onGUIEnd
System::Call 'USER32::DeleteObject(p $BrowseIcon)'
FunctionEnd
```

but you lose transparency etc.